# HP 4014 & 4015 Printing can be cleaned

Tags: laser-printer

My company bought 10 HP 4014 and 4015 printers. Both models have had an issue since we bought them - you can wipe off what was printed on the paper when you touch it. I'm guessing the fuser is not heating properly, but this is happening to *all* of these printers , both with original and refilled cartridges. What do we do?

Comment: I do realise there's a language barrier here, but could you clarify what you mean by "problem at the begining usage" - is this a problem you have when you first start printing, then it goes away, or did it do so from when the printers are new? If the printer is new and faulty, call up the people you bought them from, and insist on getting them replaced, you have a warranty for a reason, and if you've been sold faulty printers, its better to get the people who sold them to you to take care of it, rather than you or your company.

Comment: Dear Sir I mean the problem begin when the printers was new.

Comment: and are they still under warranty? If not, why didn't you take it up earlier?

Comment: Dear please help me for solving the problem.perhaps it was due to our contract with no warranty.

Comment: This isn't something thats trivial to fix, and I wouldn't be surprised if you were sold these with the full knowledge that they wouldn't work. Whoever bought gear with *no* warranty at all ought to be fired. You've been sold a bunch of lemons, and *someone* is likely to have to pay a professional work out what's the issue. Laser printers are NOT designed to be user servicable outside changing the toner cart.

Comment: I knowe this is un usual. but we bought a closed package printer and hope The HP check it all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its obvious that you got sold a load of printers that never worked properly. Its not a great technical answer, but you really need to call up the company that sold you the printers, or the local warranty agent, and insist that these printers do not work, and that you want them repaired or replaced. If necessary use very small words, or very harsh ones.

This isn't something you should fix yourself, and really, your company should get what they paid for. *Working printers*. If its some other issue, the company's service folk should have it worked out in short order. This is one of those times where you need to insist on your rights, and get a trained professional to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both printers could be faulty, but it is more likely that the problem is with the paper. Unless you are using plain 80 gsm bond paper, make sure you tell the printer (from the driver or from the front panel) what kind of paper is used. For heavy or special papers the printer may have to apply more heat in the fuser to make the toner adhere.